# in Python how do I close a file opened using os.startfile()?

Tags: file

I used os.startfile('test-conversion.pdf') to open a PDF file, but I want to close the file **and** the application that opened it.  os.startfile() launches the associated application, but probably does so using the Windows registry to do so.

How do I find out programatically which application opened it, gets its process handle, and close the application and the file?

```
import os
import subprocess

# specify the file name
file1 = 'test-conversion.pdf'

# open the file using the .startfile() method
os.startfile('test-conversion.pdf')

# open the file using the subprocess.Popen() method
subprocess.Popen([file1],shell=True)

# subprocess.Pclose([file1],shell=True)
```

I tried the last line, but it throws an error and doesn't close the file or the process.